# How to setup latex on mac?

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, mac, mactex

I have a macbook pro with OSx El Capitan Version 10.11.6 as operative system.

I have installed `texmaker` and `MacTeX-2010` on the machine.

However I can not compile latex documents. What should I do? Where can I find the `pdftex`?

Comment: Did you install MacTeX2010 or MacTeX2020? Please clarify. Any chance you could update MacOS on your system?

Comment: You might visit the MacTeX site for the MacTex2018 or MacTeX2019 version as the highest for installation on macOS 10.11. https://www.tug.org/mactex/

Comment: @Mico I installed `MacTeX2010` as I said

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return?